# Hiding context menu items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-contextmenu

There is a context menu in my application, but I want to hide its items when a particular condition is specified.
What should I do ?

This is `onCreateContextMenu` code

```
   @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        menu.setHeaderTitle("Select the Action");

        menu.add(0,0,getAdapterPosition(), Common.EDIT_POST);
        menu.add(0,1,getAdapterPosition(),Common.DELETE_POST);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable. Change its state when your condition is met. Do not add the menu items you want to hide to `menu`.

```
// Declare as global inside Activity
private customCondition = true;

...
// Check if your condition has been met and change the variable state
if(isConditionMet()) {
   customCondition = false;
} else {
   customCondition = true;
}
...
```

Now inside `onCreateContextMenu`,

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Select the Action");
    menu.add(0, 0, getAdapterPosition(), Common.EDIT_POST);

    if(!customCondition) {
        // Hide the delete post menuitem
        menu.add(0, 1, getAdapterPosition(),Common.DELETE_POST);
    }

}
```